# class file size difference when running javac ant in eclipse and command line

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am running java code with ant javac. I ran ant script in eclipse and command line. but the Java class files are differ in size. Can you please explain why there is a size differece when using javac ant script in eclipse and commandline. and how can I resolve it.

Comment: Can you look at the compiler parameters that eclipse is using for javac? What are they? What are u using on command line? And its the same JDK in both cases, right?

Answer (score 1):

Java Compiler may or may not include the following into bytecode I know of:

- Java annotations
- Javadoc specific info

There should be a difference between the actual *javac* parameters when it's called. Check Ant's config and *javac*'s default parameter values. The target Java platform version may differ too which causes .class file size differences.

If there are multiple JDK-s utilized, of course that means different class file sizes too.

Answer (score 1):

javac by default generates only line numbers in debugging info (see javac -g). In Eclipse all vars, lines and source in compiler classfile generation options are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to "resolve"; Eclipse uses its own built-in incremental compiler, and it's entirely common for compilers to produce slightly different output from the same programs.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter any ambiguity with class files compiled using ANT,
its because ANT's javac has debug mode as false by default.

Turning

> debug="true"

in javac of ANT script will generate the same class file
which is generated with maven or normal javac in cmd.